# Forcing mathematical symbols in beamer frame headers to be bold

Tags: beamer, symbols, bold, boldmath, beamer-metropolis

I am using a beamer theme with bold headers (namely, `metropolis`). It looks great... except when I have a formula in frame header, because mathematical symbols don't get bolded. I can force them using `\bm`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]{A $A$} % bad result
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[fragile]{A $\bm{A}$} % better
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Remembering always to do this is inconvenient. Is there a way to always get bold symbols there? Maybe not with `bm` but some other package, or by changing the theme in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `metropolis` theme uses `\bfseries` for `frametitle` font, so you can redefine `\bfseries` to work in both text-mode and math-mode as below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\bfseries}{%
   \not@math@alphabet\bfseries\mathbf
   \fontseries\bfdefault\selectfont
   \boldmath
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]{A $A$} % bad result
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[fragile]{A $\bm{A}$} % better
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

You might (ab-?)use `\setbeamerfont` to issue `\boldmath` in addition to `\bfseries`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries\boldmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A $\mathsf{A}$ $A$} 
x
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]